# $cordovaCamera.getPicture does not work in ios 11

Tags: ionic-framework, ios11, ngcordova

I am using a ionic v1 app deployed on an ipad running on ios 11. When  I try to run the app in ipad and click on the camera button , nothing happens. It stays as it is. I tried to look for issues mentioned similar to ios 10 and added relevant tags for info.plst file and also added the cross frame security bypass. I looked around but could not any solution to this. I have raised this question only after trying out all possible solutions that were specific for $cordovaCamera not working on ios 10. Even I tried to use the navigator.camera.getPicture() instead of $cordovaCamera.getPicture() but that didnt work either.

In my view I have

```
<a ng-click="takePicture()" style="color:#fff;">
```

In controller I have

```
$scope.takePicture = function (options) {

                  var options = {
                          destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                          sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                          allowEdit: true,
                          quality: 100,
                          targetWidth: 300,
                          targetHeight: 300,
                          encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                          popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                          saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
                          correctOrientation:true
                  };

                 $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
                                         console.log('here');

                     $scope.pictureUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

                     console.log(imageData);
                     $scope.img_update = 1;
                  }, function(err) {
                     console.log(err);
                  });

             };
```

In the controller I have also injected $cordovaCamera.

In index.html I have added

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; script-src &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; &apos;unsafe-eval&apos; *; style-src  &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; *">
```

In config.xml I have added these tags inside platform ios

```
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~2.3.0">
        <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="The app would like to access the camera when you attach photos to content." />
        <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="The app would like to access the photo library when you attach images to content." />
    </plugin>
    <edit-config target="NSCameraUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
        <string>need camera access to take pictures</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
        <string>need to photo library access to get pictures from there</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
        <string>need location access to find things nearby</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config target="NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
        <string>need to photo library access to save pictures there</string>
    </edit-config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update latest ios and android version then start following steps.

Step 1) Run this command

```
ionic cordova plugin rm camera
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera  --variable CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="your usage message" --variable PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="your usage message"
```

Step 2) Add Options like this

```
var options = {  
 // Size  
 quality: 80,  
 targetWidth: 1024,  
 targetHeight: 768,  
 // Actions  
 allowEdit: false,  
 correctOrientation: false,  
 saveToPhotoAlbum: false,  
 // iOS  
 popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions, 
 // Basic  
 encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,  
 sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,  
 destinationType: this.platform.is('ios') ? Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,    
 };
```

And you Done.

Comment: @ArkoD Please try above solution this will help you.

Comment: I'll give it a try today and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @ArkoD OK. Thanks

Comment: Seems to have fixed the gallery. I can now pick up photos from the picture library however tapping on the camera icon does nothing.

Comment: Yes I did. It finally worked after updating the ios version. Android it was working fine earlier and no change in code was needed. Thanks for your help. If you can edit you answer and include the latest comment, I can mark it as the correct answer.